# Debug android application by upgrading production(signed) apk

Tags: android, debugging, adb, apk, sign

I can download my old apk(s) as signed apk(s) from Google Play.
I have latest version of my app on android studio.
I want to debug SQLiteOpenHelper onUpgrade method so I need to upgrade the apk but I do not have old apk signed with debug key.
So when I install old production apk and want to debug from Android Studio I get INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE error.
Is there any way to solve this issue?
Thanks,
Baris

PS: Writing some debug information (Log.d()), signing the apk with production, re-install the apk and watch the Android Monitor for debug info is workaround but I want real debug from android studio.

Comment: yes, there is ... sign debug apk with the same key as old release

Comment: You might also consider creating a debug variant of your APK so that the two can be installed simultaneously and you can test your open helper without interfering with your current install of the app. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Comment: I did test of upgrade using this method. Not sure if you have tried it already.
I installed the old signed APK first. Created test data. New version of code is present in Android Studio with incremented DB version. I created signed APK (Running of code will not upgrade) using same key. Moved the APK to phone (used gmail as mediator). Click install and it will upgrade just like normal production upgrade. Please try and let me know.

Comment: When you say "re-install the apk and watch the Android Monitor for debug info", I wonder how you do that.  When I reinstall the signed update, it installs, but I don't see the debug info.  Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53215222/897007